# Mandrill Reply-to

Tags: php, mandrill

Today I sign-up Mandrill account to learn how it's work. [This is my PHP code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ca4c6fe388c465d8076) to send a simple email:

```
<?php

$apikey = 'API_KEY_HERE';

require_once 'Mandrill.php';
$mandrill = new Mandrill($apikey);

$message = new stdClass();
$message->html = "html message";
//$message->text = "text body";
$message->subject = "email subject";
$message->from_email = "from@email.com";
$message->from_name  = "My App Name";
$message->to = array(array("email" => "recipient@email.com"));
$message->track_opens = true;

$response = $mandrill->messages->send($message);

var_dump($response);
?>
```

This script use [this Bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php).

I wonder how to insert Reply-to email address variable in the script. What is the variable name? I'm looking at the [docs page](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html) but I get stucked.

I'm new to PHP. I really appreciate your helps. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok. I found it.

```
$message->headers = array('Reply-To' => 'another@email.com');
```