# Mandrill Reply-To Header when sending via Node.js

Tags: email, mailchimp, mandrill, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to figure out how to add a reply-to header to emails sent from my website using mandrill transactional API. I have tried multiple options but none is working. I want to implement a contact us form and send emails from my domain to support email where they can easily reply back to users.

```
{
"key":"xxxxxxx",
"template_name": "welcome-email",
"template_content":{},
"message": {
    "merge" : true,
    "global_merge_vars" : [ {
        "name" : "my_h_tag",
        "content" : "THIS IS WORKING"
    }],
    "merge_vars": [],
    "merge_language": "handlebars",
    "async" : false,
    "subject":"Testing Revamp Api",
    "from_email":"hello@mydomain",
    "to":[
        {
            "email":"user email",
            "type":"to"
        }
    ],
    "headers":[
        {
        "reply_to":"user email eneterd in contact form"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your general approach is correct, passing `Reply-To` via `headers` should be supported, but the header is called `reply-to` (with the dash), while you use an underscore. Have you tried to use the dash?

Also, per documentation, `headers` [should be an object](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-using-message-template/).

```json
{
  "key": "xxxxxxx",
  // ...
  "message": {
    // ...
    "headers": {
      "reply-to": "user email eneterd in contact form"
    }
  }
}
```

Related: [Mandrill Reply-to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23522519/240963)